# How to transform API output to columns for a table (UIBakery)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, transform

I am trying to map each array so I can use all objects in a table. I can't figure out how to map the objects inside the billingDetails array.

**Output API**

```
{
invoiceRequests: [
{
    orderId: "987654",
    billingDetails: {
        firstName: "Eva",
        surname: "Jans",
        streetName: "Maasweg",
        houseNumber: "1",
        zipCode: "3943",
        city: "Paris",
        countryCode: "FR"
},
```

This is what I tried to transform the data

```
return [{{data}}].map(item => {
  return {
    Ordernumber: item.invoiceRequests.orderId,
    Firstname: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.firstName,
    Surname: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.surname,
    Street: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.streetName,
    Number: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.houseNumber,
    Postalcode: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.zipCode,
    Cicty: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.city,
    Country: item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails.countryCode,
    };
});
```

I receive this error:

```
{
name: "Error",
message: "item.invoiceRequests.billingDetails is undefined"
}
```

I am able to extract the orderId, this is only one array deep while the other objects are two arrays deep.

Hope you could help!

Kind regards,

Kevin

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yOFP.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/meuzk.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuoCd.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` over `data.invoiceRequests` instead.

```js
const data={invoiceRequests:[{orderId:"987654",billingDetails:{firstName:"Eva",surname:"Jans",streetName:"Maasweg",houseNumber:"1",zipCode:"3943",city:"Paris",countryCode:"FR"}}]};
const res = data.invoiceRequests.map(o => ({
    Ordernumber: o.orderId,
    Firstname: o.billingDetails.firstName,
    Surname: o.billingDetails.surname,
    Street: o.billingDetails.streetName,
    Number: o.billingDetails.houseNumber,
    Postalcode: o.billingDetails.zipCode,
    Cicty: o.billingDetails.city,
    Country: o.billingDetails.countryCode
}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I run the code snippet it looks like what I need. I can't figure out how to set it up correctly in my web app. 

I get the errors: 
- Data is already declared. Use {{data}} variable to access the result of the previous step
- Res is already declared. Use {{res}} variable to access the result of the previous step
- 'return' statement is missing in multi-statement code

I will add the screenshots of this error to the original post. 

I am a newbie so it might be a simple error to solve

Comment: @Kevin Don't declare the `data` variable again; it's just for demonstration in the snippet. Replace `data` with the name of your own array variable. Where are you running this?

Comment: Thanks again, i will try to change the name. I am running on UIBakery